# Python Expert: how to inherit built-in class and override every member function w.r.t. the base-class member function?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, built-in, built-in-types

It is known that in Python, due to optimization concerns, we cannot add/modify member functions of a built-in class, e.g., adding an `sed` function to the built-in `str` class to perform `re.sub()`. Thus, the only way to achieve so is to inherit the class (or subclassing). i.e.,

```
class String(str):
    def __init__(self, value='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def sed(self, src, tgt):
        return String(re.sub(src, tgt, self))
```

The problem with this is that after sub-classing, member functions return base-class instance instead of the inherited class instance. For example, I would like to chain String edits `String(' A b C  d E [!]  ').sed(...).lower().sed(...).strip().sed('\[.*\]', '').split()` and so on. However, functions such as `.lower()` and `.strip()` returns an `str` instead of `String`, so cannot perform `.sed(...)` afterwards. And I do not want to keep casting to `String` after every function call.

So I did a manual over-ride of every base-class methods as follows:

```
class String(str):
    for func in dir(str):
        if not func.startswith('_'):
            exec(f'{func}=lambda *args, **kwargs: [(String(i) if type(i)==str else i) for i in [str.{func}(*args, **kwargs)]][0]')

    def __init__(self, value='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def sed(self, src, tgt):
        return String(re.sub(src, tgt, self))
```

However, not every member function returns a simple `str` object, e.g., for functions such as `.split()`, they return a list of `str`; other functions like `.isalpha()` or `.find()` return boolean or integer. In general, I want to add more string-morphing functions and do not want to manually over-ride member functions of each return type in order to return inherited-class objects rather than base-class objects. So is there a more elegant way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: The elegant way is not to do it. In your example I see no added value for your `sed()` function to the string class, but I see a very specific use-case which ends up as a string replace. If your string customisations do not exceed that complexity then it's more elegant and expressive to your fellow coders to use well known operations like `re.sub()` instead of your own wrapping.

If your customization is really justified, then the answer is your own string class where you override any operations you see fit. If you expose such low level operations maybe your class API is not yet finished.

Comment: @FlorinC. Here I am talking about elite coding, so don't be puzzled by the `re.sub()` in my example (which makes little difference with `.sed()`). The goal is to patch every function inside the base function, turning outputs to be the inherited instance instead of the base instance.

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in classes are not designed to support that style of inheritance
easily. Also, the whole idea seems flawed to my eye. Even if you do figure out
a way to solve the problem as you've framed it, what's the advantage over good
old functions?

```
# Special String objects with new methods.

s = String('foo bar')
result = s.sed('...', '...')

# Regular str instances passed to ordinary functions.

s = 'foo bar'
result = sed(s, '...', '...')
```

That said, here's one way to try. I have not tested it
extensively, it might have a flaw, and I would never use it in real code.
The basic idea is to capture objects returned during low-level
attribute access, and if the object is callable return
a wrapped version of it that will perform the needed
data conversions.

```
import re
from functools import wraps

class String(str):

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        return wrapped(obj) if callable(obj) else obj

    def __init__(self, value='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def sed(self, src, tgt):
        return re.sub(src, tgt, self)

def wrapped(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*xs, **kws):
        obj = func(*xs, **kws)
        return convert(obj)

    return wrapper

def convert(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return String(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [convert(x) for x in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, tuple):
        return tuple(convert(x) for x in obj)
    else:
        return obj
```

Demo:

```
s = String('foo bar')
got = s.sed('foo', 'bzz').upper().split()
print(got)
print(type(got))
print(type(got[0]))
```

Output:

```
['BZZ', 'BAR']
<class 'list'>
<class '__main__.String'>
```

Comment: My whole idea is to be able to chain string-edit functions for short coding. I don't see anything flawed inside. Btw, modding every function inside the original class is a very common technique, not just for built-in classes.

Comment: @xuancong84 Opinions vary. However, the code is no shorter one way or the other, as demonstrated above. And modifying every function in another class is most assuredly not a common technique: I know about it; I've seen it done; but nowhere near common.